# How not to avoid using reference numbers as nouns in an academic article

Tags: academia, reference

I wrote a scientific article for a conference, and a reviewer criticized it as he said that in my manuscript “references are used as nouns”. I assume he was refering to instances of the following type, although he did not say so explicitly:

> 1. According to [20]
> 2. …is described in [17]
> 3. …as highlighted in [7]

(The conference proceedings specifies this in-text numerical reference style.)

Is it really wrong to use reference numbers in this way? In any case, how can I satisfy him by rewriting these examples to avoid doing this?

Comment: He is sort of right, you must have misunderstood him when he said: **They are always used as nouns** - He probably said: **References are always proceded by nouns** not always, of course - There will always be one rule that causes conflict with another one. Get used to it.
Nevertheless, I don't remember to have seen any references proceded by verb or any other thing that isn't a noun, and I can't think of any as well.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what your question is. Usually you would write, "According to Anderson, etc." with a footnote reference either after the principal author's name or at the end of your sentence. What am I missing?

Comment: You should check out [writers.se] also.

Comment: I'd guess he's saying the reference should be parenthetical: if you remove it, the sentence should still make sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — How is it that I can understand the question and you people cannot? The question may not be appropriate to EL&U, but it's certainly not unclear.

Comment: There is probably a question going beyond the English involved. Correct attribution probably demands that the authors be cited in the body-text, not merely as footnotes. But style guides cover these things. // I'd suggest that '... references are used as nouns' means  '... you are wrongly using bare numerical references when nouns (the authors / works) are also required'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I don't think so. This sounds like a scientific journal where there are no footnotes or in-text references, but all the references are endnotes. It would be helpful if the poster clarified the subject area and the referencing style of the journal.

Comment: Related on Academia.SE: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49487/20058

Comment: The comment of @sumelic also helped me to detect this issue

Comment: @Haseo — The poster did not quote the referee as saying "references are **always** used as nouns" but wrote that they were used as nouns **in his manuscript**". This is precisely what the examples he quote show: "according to [noun]", "as described in [noun]", where instead of a noun such as "Smith's paper" we have [17]. Your statement about references being proceeded by nouns is nonsense. In this style you most often write a sentence with the reference at the end of the sentence, not as part of it. Hence, it will be preceeded by whatever word ends the sentence. See the IEEE document.

Answer (score 4):

You are right in thinking the examples you cite are what the reviewer means by *“references are used as nouns”* (*see* IEEE Citation Reference, below).

**Is this really wrong?**

In my view it cannot be judged ‘wrong’ as at least one very respectable journal allows it — it is more a question of writing style and house style. First, the evidence that some journals allow it:

[image: IEEE Citation Reference style for text references]

*[IEEE (Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers) Citation Reference, 2009]*

Why, then, does your reviewer not like it (and presumably the house style of your conference proceedings and other journals *not* allow it)? I think it is for the reason mentioned by @sumelic in his comment — a conviction that the sentence should be able to stand alone, without references.

Certainly the style you use is ugly if read aloud, and can be avoided because it won’t work with superscript reference numbers. To digress a little, there are three main citation styles for references (in my area of science), superscript numbers, numbers in parentheses written within the text, and author/date written within the text.

If one considers superscripts (which is probably the oldest form), you can write “DNA consists of a double helix<sup>1</sup>”, but obviously *not* “According to <sup>1</sup> DNA consists of a double helix”.

However the author/date style of referencing allows this. You can write “DNA consists of a double helix (Watson and Crick, 1953)” or “According to Watson and Crick (1953) DNA consists of a double helix”.

I imagine this latter is what has led to the use of the style of “According to [20]” with the later introduction of in-text numerals (easier to set in type). However some regard in-text numerals in the same way as superscripts, and disapprove of this usage.

**How can it be replaced?**

First check any ‘Instructions to Authors’ or past conference proceedings to find out what the house style is. If we consider your first example:

> According to [20]

I suggest two alternatives.

(i) Refer to the authors of the paper:

> According to Smith and Brown [20]

e.g.

[image: Example of reference with authors mentioned]

(ii) Use the passive:

> It has been suggested/proposed/reported [20]

e.g.

[image: Example of reference in passive construction]

(In this case put the reference at the end of the sentence so that it cannot be considered part of it.)

I am sure you can adopt these for examples 2 and 3 yourself. Dealing with the individual quirks of reviewers is often galling, but one has to grit one’s teeth and do what is requested to get published.

Comment: 'According to Smith and Brown [20]' vs 'According to [20]'? Perhaps Smith and Brown should be allowed to have a say in which attribution style they consider more respectful?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Is this meant to be a joke?

Comment: I'm a scientist, and while I've certainly seen articles with say _various authors [1,2,3,4] have proposed a different mechanism_ I've never come across _The different mechanism proposed by [1,2,3,4]_. The numerals are used as a parenthetical, not as part of the matrix sentence. If you wish to disagree (in an 'answer' on ELU), you need to provide supporting evidence rather than personal anecdotal material.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — There are more things in heaven and earth… It would be good if the standards you set for ELU were applied more consistently, but in an effort to make ELU a useful resource I've provided the documentation you required, tried to put things in perspective and depersonalized things a little. By the way. It sounds as if you understand the question quite clearly. Shouldn't you reconsider your vote to put it on hold as unclear?

Comment: I don't think that was my close-vote reason. Only the majority reason/s get listed. Lack of research (advice from a style-guide) shown by OP, and POB (The next style guide might advocate 'don't use bracketed numbers as nouns – which is why I consider virtually all questions about style inappropriate).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Including punctuation?

Comment: Certainly. There's far more scope for opinion when 'correct punctuation' is argued over. You might appreciate [this thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157703/whats-the-difference-between-i-e-and-that-is).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — That's my point. But it's a common topic that is generally allowed here. (Even if the best answers point out that there are generally stylistic alternatives, there are some styles of punctuation that are clearly wrong because they give a false meaning.)

Comment: Returning to the actual question here, "a reviewer criticized it as he said that in my manuscript 'references are used as nouns' ", the reviewer (and one would hope OP while retaining said reviewer) obviously doesn't subscribe to IEEE style. These things are opinion-based.