# Did I use "That is" correctly?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, syntactic-analysis

How would I go about using "That is" in the sentence(s) below?

"Everyone in the town was poor. That is, except for one man."

Should I use a hyphen/comma/semi-colon (or something else) in between "poor" and "that" to connect the two sentences? Or is it fine the way it is?

Comment: It feels off to me. I would simply say *Everyone in the town was poor, except for one man.*

Comment: Or perhaps - *Everyone in the town was poor:  Everyone, that is, except for one man*.

Answer (score -1):

Try this link ["That is" vs. "i.e."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48278/that-is-vs-i-e//)

This phrase is used to link two independent sentences which are related. The first sentence should be followed by semicolon then the related sentence followed by comma. "Everyone in the town was poor; that is, except for one man."

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Link-only answers, even to SE pages, are frowned upon. Consider summarizing the info from the link (but keep the link as well).

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.